# Google Appengine oauth token points to the wrong account

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, oauth

Basically, I have a GCP account where I have 4 appengine projects. And I wanted to grant access to another user to one of my projects. The user account was a valid gmail account but had never been registered (or logged in) on GCP before.

Now, this user created a new project in his account, and wanted to deploy his project (using maven) but constantly got a 404 Error detailing that the project did not exist. We then tried using "my project id" (which I had given him access to) and he could successfully upload in that project_id.

So, it looks like the appcfg_oauth2_token_java file is pointing at the wrong "project container or account" and hence pointing at projects in my account instead of his.

Could anyone tell me how to switch it back to pointing to his account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Apparently, it seems like the GCP console doesn't get that well updated when creating a new project. I have read in other posts that the desired project is available after exactly 24 hours. So to avoid the wait, basically create your project through the "google command line console" with the following command: `gcloud app create` and then a list of regions will be shown and just type the one you prefer. And that's it!

The app deployed instantly!